# App deployment failed. Please try again.

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have developed windows phone app. I am getting following error when I run my app on device instead of emulator.

**Error** :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Demo, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Begin application manifest generation
1>  No changes detected. Application manifest file is up to date
1>  Begin Xap packaging
1>  No changes detected. Xap package is up to date
2>------ Deploy started: Project: Demo, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Deployment of application to device failed.
2>Error: App deployment failed. Please try again. 
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am not getting where is the issue. Can someone please help me?

Comment: is it working on emulator ? or have you opened your phone developer lock ? or is your phone active means you open your start screen ?

Comment: it's working on emulator. My phone is unlock. But now it's working. I have restarted my device :)

Answer (score 12):

Reboot Your Windows Phone.

Always works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall your app, and then deploy it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this issue is about your Hard Disk, check if you have enough free storage space and try running a chkdsk.

Otherwise can be your Emulator Configuration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_boottovhd